# "Que tout le monde aille bien" et "J'espère que tout le monde va bien"

Tags: usage, correspondance

> Bonjour à chacune et à chacun,
>
> Que tout le monde aille bien.

Peut-on commencer un e-mail comme ça au lieu de

> J'espère que tout le monde va bien.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Que tout le monde aille bien* est plutôt une formule qu'on utiliserait pour prendre congé ou pour conclure une lettre. Elle n'est pas vraiment adaptée au début d'un e-mail, mais plutôt à sa fin, par exemple avec une salutation ou une formule de politesse. Pour une formule moins solennelle,  on peut dire *portez-vous bien* ou *prenez soin de vous*.

*J'espère que tout le monde va bien* est tout à fait adéquat pour entamer un e-mail informel. On pourrait aussi écrire *j'espère que vous vous portez tous bien*.