# Que répondre "J'espère que vous allez bien" ? - email professionnel

Tags: email

La plupart du temps, les recruteurs commencent leurs emails par :

> J'espère que tu vas bien.

D'habitude, je réponds :

> Je vais bien merci, j'espère que tu vas bien aussi.

Je me pose la question : Est-ce qu'il existe une autre réponse plus sexy ?

Comment: Are you sure that they use tu and not vous?

Comment: yeap, as the recruiter is from Canada :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I modified my answer.

Comment: Welcome to FSE by the way:-)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J'écrirais :

> Je vais bien merci, j'espère que tu te portes bien aussi.

> Ça va bien merci, j'espère que tu es en pleine forme aussi.

> Ça va bien ; merci pour ton intérêt. Comment vas-tu ?
>
> **La différence est mince, on en convient, mais le fait de solliciter directement votre interlocuteur est une preuve d'attention sincère**. source : https://www.marieclaire.fr/,pourquoi-il-faut-arreter-d-ecrire-j-espere-que-vous-allez-bien-dans-vos-mails-pro,848644.asp
>
> Voir aussi https://madame.lefigaro.fr/business/pourquoi-faut-il-arreter-de-commencer-ses-mails-par-jespere-que-vous-allez-bien-deconfinement-050520-180929:
>
> d'où l'extrait qui suit :
>
> On lui préfèrera toutefois la question : «Comment allez-vous ?» Selon
> l'experte, contrairement à la précédente formule, qui n'attend pas de
> réponse, celle-ci invite vraiment l'interlocuteur à donner de ses
> nouvelles, et lui donne ainsi plus envie de le faire. «Il faut piocher
> dans un langage sincère, éloigné des phrases toutes faites et des
> "mots bateaux". Ces derniers donnent l’impression d’une distance alors
> que le but est de créer de la proximité.»

[J'imagine que pour un e-mail professionnel 'j'espère que tu pètes la forme' ne se dit pas mais je le trouve irresistible et tant que non locuteur natif:-)!]

Questions connexes sur FSE :

[J'espère que vous allez parfaitement et ses dérivées](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44399/jesp%c3%a8re-que-vous-allez-parfaitement-et-ses-d%c3%a9riv%c3%a9es)

[Remplacer « J'espère que tu vas bien »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32802/remplacer-jesp%c3%a8re-que-tu-vas-bien)

["Que tout le monde aille bien" et "J'espère que tout le monde va bien"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41809/que-tout-le-monde-aille-bien-et-jesp%c3%a8re-que-tout-le-monde-va-bien)  (fin de message plutôt)

Voir aussi : https://ohchouette.com/pourquoi-il-faut-arreter-decrire-jespere-que-vous-allez-bien-dans-vos-mails-pro/